# Create bones with a python script

Tags: python, scripting, error, .fbx, bvh

I am new to asking questions on S/O, so if the question is vague, let me know. I have an issue with trying to create bones in blender and coverting it a bvh or any other file format( i.e. fbx, obj, etc). I am working with this mocap code

https://github.com/SpectralVectors/PosePipe

There is a section that says to generate bones, and that code is here:

```
class SkeletonBuilder(bpy.types.Operator):
```

With :

```
bpy.ops.armature.bone_primitive_add(name="clavicle_l")
        clavicle_l = bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones["clavicle_l"]
        bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones["clavicle_l"].tail[2] = 0.1
        clavicle_l.parent = spine03
```

When I generate bones, the lower half creates a useable skeleton and the upper half doesn't and produces this error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\__init__.py", line 295, in execute
    return export_bvh.save(context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\export_bvh.py", line 277, in save
    write_armature(
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\export_bvh.py", line 213, in write_armature
    bones_decorated = [DecoratedBone(bone_name) for bone_name in serialized_names]
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\export_bvh.py", line 213, in <listcomp>
    bones_decorated = [DecoratedBone(bone_name) for bone_name in serialized_names]
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\export_bvh.py", line 195, in __init__
    self.pose_imat = self.pose_mat.inverted()
ValueError: Matrix.invert(ed): matrix does not have an inverse
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be grateful

Comment: Fails to install for me.  You're going to have to contact the author on this one.

Comment: @MartyFouts, thank you.